# MVC inside Drupal 7 nginx url rewrite

Tags: model-view-controller, drupal, nginx

### Senario

### I have a Drupal 7 installation with nginx configuration like [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/)

And i want a custom MVC app to be run on a subfolder named `mvcp`

for that i use this

```
 location /mvcp {
  root /var/www/html/site/mvcp;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
}
```

on `curl -I url` i get this

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 05:40:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
```

EDIT

modified to

```
 location /mvcp {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /mvcp/index.php?q=$uri&$args break;
 }
```

now main `/mvcp/` works but not the sub paths..

Comment: You have an `mvcp` element in the path twice, is that intentional?

Comment: @RichardSmith on the `root` ? sorry i don't understand ..

Answer (score 0):

In your original post, the location block looks in `/var/www/html/site/mvcp/mvcp` because the `root` and URI are concatenated to form the local path.

In your EDIT, `try_files` is incorrect as the last element should be a `=code` or URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). Remove the `break` element, try:

```
location /mvcp {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /mvcp/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Comment: @NikhilM You will need to look at the nginx error log file. On my system it's `/var/log/nginx-error.log`, but your system may use different defaults or it may be explicitly specified in the `nginx.conf` file(s)